# how can I set up unix command with C, especially with "system()"?

Tags: c, unix, system

I'm just getting started with C.

What I want to do is issue Unix commands from C, especially with `system()`.But if I have code like this, it can only access files in the same directory.

```
system("./Test");
```

But I want to use that code in any directory. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`system()` forwards its string parameter to the native command line handler - e.g. `/bin/sh` on Unix or `cmd.exe` on Windows. You can use whatever command or path those whould take. Of course, such code is not portable.

Answer (score 2):

```
system("/any/other/folder/Test");
```

calling command via `system` is like calling command via command line interface so even the path of your command is `../../any/other/folder/Test`, you call it with

```
system("../../any/other/folder/Test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass an absolute path as parameter

```
system("/your/folder/Test");
```

Comment: if that is parent folder, can I put like "../../your/folder/Test"? I'm not sure that this is the only solution, but thanx alot.